# Where is the laravel error file located? or Is there a default error log in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a medium project -with laravel- for quite a long time now and of course I use the debugger of the framework -laravel-, but now from time to time I see the page of error but there is just "whoops something went wrong without" without any specifications for the error, and I see it a lot in ajax requests, but I just actualize the page and its gone!;

**Finally the error show up again and I could see it in my terminal with the command tail down here**

this is what I got

```
[2016-12-28 14:54:04] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\shop\tess\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 D:\shop\tess\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(25): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher(NULL, 'AES-256-CBC')
#1 D:\shop\tess\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(731): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
```

I've found this on github it helped https://github.com/orchestral/testbench/issues/93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the errors with the following command  `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log` Could be different errors

Comment: what does this command do? just echos the errors log at the moment you typed it ?

Comment: @brahimm [2 seconds of Googling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) is all it takes.

Comment: finaly I got the error  Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher(NULL, 'AES-256-CBC')

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `APP_DEBUG` is set to `true` in your `.env` file

Comment: I said Im using the Debugger

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear that you knew this. Try `dd(config('app.debug'));` to see if it is actually located? There might be some kind of local permission issue.

Comment: the debugger is working fine, and that was the reason of this question.

Comment: Seeing your edited question with the solution: please next time try to make clear what you are asking. Your question title should be `Where is the laravel error file located?` or `Is there a default error log in Laravel?` but not `What would be the reason to see the“Whoops something went wrong” without error details`

Comment: OK ! its because I didn't know what to look for or what to ask ! but thanks anyway